# What is the interest rate charged on negative cash balances?

Tags: railroad-tycoon-2

In *Railroad Tycoon 2: Platinum*, what is the interest rate charged on the negative cash balance of a chairman or company? Is the interest rate equal to the prime rate, or is it greater? What determines the interest charged on negative cash balances?